# Android - Animate a view and change his real position (and another view follow with behavior dependency)

Tags: android, animation, view, behavior, viewdraghelper

I'm trying to animate my appBar using a ViewDragHelper, when I drag it down it should start an animation and go down.

On top I have another view (pink in [the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrWKR.gif)) that "follow" my appbar with a behavior (the top view depends on AppBarLayout).

[As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrWKR.gif) the appbar is animated but the "real" position do not change and, obviously, my top frame doesn't move.

In order to animate I use the following code:

```
@Override
public void onViewReleased(final View releasedChild, float xvel, float yvel) {
    super.onViewReleased(releasedChild, xvel, yvel);
    if (releasedChild.getTop() > childHeight) {
        Log.e("TAG", "SHOULD SCROLL " + releasedChild.getTop() + " > " + childHeight);
        final int offset = height - releasedChild.getTop() - 100;
        ViewCompat.animate(releasedChild).translationY(offset).setDuration(1000).setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator()).start();
    } else {
        Log.e("TAG", "SHOULD NOT SCROLL " + releasedChild.getTop() + " < " + childHeight);
        eleasedChild.offsetTopAndBottom(-releasedChild.getTop());
    }
    if (mDragFrameLayoutController != null) {
         mDragFrameLayoutController.onDragDrop(false);
    }
}
```

I've tried with many other animations:

```
TranslateAnimation scale = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.f, offset);
scale.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
scale.setDuration(3000L);
scale.setFillEnabled(true);
scale.setFillAfter(true);
scale.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
```

or

```
ObjectAnimator moveY = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(releasedChild, "y", releasedChild.getTop(), offset);
AnimatorSet as = new AnimatorSet();
as.play(moveY);
as.start();
```

All these snippets give me the same result.

The only way I found to move the view is using offset but this doesn't animate, it just moves down...

```
releasedChild.offsetTopAndBottom(offset);
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

on my viewDragHelper I overrode the following methods:

```
        @Override
        public int getViewVerticalDragRange(View child) {
            return getMeasuredHeight() - child.getMeasuredHeight();
        }


        @Override
        public void onViewReleased(View releasedChild, float xvel, float yvel) {
            super.onViewReleased(releasedChild, xvel, yvel);
            if(yvel>0) {
                mDragHelper.settleCapturedViewAt(releasedChild.getLeft(), getMeasuredHeight()-releasedChild.getMeasuredHeight());
            } else {
                mDragHelper.settleCapturedViewAt(releasedChild.getLeft(), 0);
            }
            invalidate();
        }
```

then on my custom view I overrode the following method:

```
   @Override
   public void computeScroll() {
       super.computeScroll();
       if (mDragHelper.continueSettling(true)) {
           ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
       }
   }
```

And everything worked fine!
I hope this can help someone in future.